# Switch Theme use under the Drawer vs PopupMenuItem

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Although the Switch structure is the same, the Switch button under the PopupMenuItem works once. it does not open and close, and once it runs, the button appearance does not change. There is no problem with the Switch under the Drawer. Why is under PopupMenuItem not working properly?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: block.darkThemeEnabled,

      initialData: false,

      builder: (context, snapshot) =>
          MaterialApp(
            theme: snapshot.data?ThemeData.dark():ThemeData.light(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("switch theme"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: (context){
                    return[
                      PopupMenuItem(child: ListTile(title: Text("Dark Theme"), trailing: Switch(value: snapshot.data, onChanged: block.changeTheme),)), //Problem
                      PopupMenuItem(child: ListTile(title: Text("click2"))),
                      PopupMenuItem(child: ListTile(title: Text("click3"))),
                      //PopupMenuItem(child: SwitchListTile(title: Text("Dark Theme2"),value: snapshot.data, onChanged: block.changeTheme))
                    ];
                  })
                ],
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Text("Switch Theme use->Drawer vs PopupMenuItem"),
              ),
              drawer: Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("dark theme"),
                      trailing: Switch(
                        value: snapshot.data,
                        onChanged: block.changeTheme,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}

class Block {
  final _themeContol = StreamController<bool>();

  get changeTheme => _themeContol.sink.add;

  get darkThemeEnabled => _themeContol.stream;
}

final block = Block();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Use `StatefulBuilder` 
Step 2: add function changeTheme1(bool value) 
code snippet

```
PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: (context) {
      return [
            PopupMenuItem(
                child: ListTile(
              title: Text("Dark Theme"),
              trailing: StatefulBuilder(builder:
                  (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                return Switch(
                  value: switchValue,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    block.changeTheme1(newValue);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                );
              }),
            )), 
                        
...
class Block {
      ...
      void changeTheme1(bool value) {
        _themeContol.sink.add(value);
      }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  bool switchValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: block.darkThemeEnabled,
      initialData: false,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switchValue = snapshot.data;

        return MaterialApp(
          theme: snapshot.data ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("switch theme"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: (context) {
                  return [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("Dark Theme"),
                      trailing: StatefulBuilder(builder:
                          (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                        return Switch(
                          value: switchValue,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            block.changeTheme1(newValue);
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        );
                      }),
                    )), //Problem
                    PopupMenuItem(child: ListTile(title: Text("click2"))),
                    PopupMenuItem(child: ListTile(title: Text("click3"))),
                  ];
                })
              ],
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text("Switch Theme use->Drawer vs PopupMenuItem"),
            ),
            drawer: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text("dark theme"),
                    trailing: Switch(
                      value: snapshot.data,
                      onChanged: block.changeTheme,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Block {
  final _themeContol = StreamController<bool>();

  void changeTheme1(bool value) {
    _themeContol.sink.add(value);
  }

  get changeTheme => _themeContol.sink.add;

  get darkThemeEnabled => _themeContol.stream;
}

final block = Block();
```